# Expected error of simplifying to a geometric distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value

While reading an [answer related to solving a problem with a geometric distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/199884/33929), the following question occurred to me.

The answer gives two possibilities for replying the OP's question. In the second one (Changing number) he's actually using a geometric distribution with pobability of success $\theta$. In the first one (Fixed Number), however, the probability of success is not fixed, as it decreases for each new trial $\theta_i = \dfrac{1}{1000-i}$.

I am wondering what is the **expected error** one would commit if he computes $E[k]$ as in "changing number" when in fact the "fixed number" is the most adequate solution. I think it might make sense to model the distribution as a geometric one for sake of simplicity. What can you say about this error? Can you provide a bound?

Answer (score 0):

Say there are $n$ numbers in total.

If the number is changing every time, then every trial is independent and the number of trials to have the correct guess follows a geometric distribution, and the expectation is $n$.

If the number is fixed, then you are equally likely to have the correct guess in each trial. Therefore the distribution in this time is a discrete uniform, and the expectation is 
$$ \frac {n(n + 1)} {2} \times \frac {1} {n} = \frac {n + 1} {2}$$

So what do you mean by error? Is it the difference
$$ n - \frac {n + 1} {2} = \frac {n - 1} {2}$$

Comment: If the number is fixed, you are not equally likely to have the correct guess in each trial because the numbers you have tried can be discarded. The probability of success increases after each trial, isn't it?

Comment: You are talking about the conditional probability that given all the previous guesses failed, the probability that the next guess will be correct, and this is obviously increasing with the number of trials. I am talking about the marginal probability. Put it in other way, you can treat the guesses as a sequence from a permutation of the $n$ numbers, so it is equally likely that the correct guess occur in each position.

Comment: +1 thanks for the explanation. Just to clarify, the probability $p_k$ in the answer I linked is the conditional probability of given all the previous guesses failed until $k-1$, that we get a correct guess in $k$, is that correct?

Comment: yes that is what I meant.