# Finding the chances on $n$-th try without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In Finan's probability book 13.19

> A box contains 100 computer mice of which 95 are defective. One mouse
>   is taken from the box at a time (without replacement) until a non-defective
>   mouse is found. Let $X$ be the number of mouses you have to take out in order
>   to find one that is not defective. Find $P(X = n)$.

I thought the way to do this is

${{95!(100-n+1)!}\over{100!(95-n+1)!}}{5\over100-n+1}$

and indeed such is the way it seems from

[Repeating something with (1/n)th chance of success n times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199869/repeating-something-with-1-nth-chance-of-success-n-times)

see answer from copper.hat there,

but in the book the answer is

$P(X=n)= {95\over100}{94\over99}{93\over98}...{95-n+2\over100-n+2}{5\over100-n+1}.$

Why is it $-n+2$?

Comment: Note that you need to draw $n-1$ defectives in a row, so you need $n-1$ terms, and you start from $95-0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have two positive integers $k<m$, then
$$\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}=\frac{m\cdot(m-1)\cdot(m-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot  (m-k+1)\cdot \color{red}{(m-k)\cdot(m-k-1)\cdot(m-k-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot2\cdot 1}}{\color{red}{(m-k)\cdot(m-k-1)\cdot(m-k-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot 2\cdot 1}}
=m\cdot(m-1)\cdot(m-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot (m-k+1).$$

Taking $m=95$ and $k=n-1$, we get
$${{95!}\over{(95-n+1)!}}=95\cdot 94\cdot 93\cdot\ldots\cdot (95-n+2).$$

Similarly (and taking the multiplicative inverse of both sides) we have
$${{(100-n+1)!}\over{100!}}={1\over 100\cdot 99\cdot 98\cdot\ldots\cdot (100-n+2)}.$$

So indeed
$$P(X=n)= {95\over100}{94\over99}{93\over98}...{95-n+2\over100-n+2}{5\over100-n+1}={{95!(100-n+1)!}\over{100!(95-n+1)!}}{5\over100-n+1}.$$

---

Note that the above works for $m>k>0$, but in some way also for $k=0$. If $k=0$, then we simply get $\frac{m!}{m!}=1$. As you can see, in the case $n=1$ (so $k=n-1=0$) the left fractions in the answer of the book simply disappear (just like a sum iterating from $0$ up to $-1$ is equal to $0$, products of nothing are equal to $1$), while your left fraction turns into $1$, so your answer agrees with the one of the book for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Wouldn't my notation return the correct probability for $n=1$ which is $5\over100$?

Comment: @agblt Yes you're right. I was confusing $m-k$ and $k$. Now it should be correct.

Comment: @agblt Is my remark clear? I added a little part about products.

Comment: Working on it...

Comment: It seems that you are saying that the book's formula and mine are only equivalent when $n\ge2$, and I do see that from trying it out. My only question now is, is it true to say that the book's formula will not work for $n=1$?, or am I missing something?

Comment: @agblt After editing a little more it's certainly correct now. I hope I didn't confuse you. Your answer is equal to that of the book for all $n\geq 1$. There was still an aftermath in my answer from the $k$ and $m-k$ confusion.

Comment: @agblt To make it a little more clear about the answer of the book: for $n=4$ we have ${95\over100}{94\over99}{93\over98}$, for $n=3$ we have ${95\over100}{94\over99}$, for $n=2$ we have ${95\over100}$ and for $n=1$ we have $1$ (empty product).

Comment: Sorry, what is empty product? Wouldn't books answer for $n=1$ be ${96\over101}{5\over100}$ or are you saying it's impossible so we ignore it and treat it as 1?

Comment: @agblt With the empty product I mean the product of zero elements. It's defined as $1$ (similarly the sum of zero elements is $0$). It would not be $96\over101$: you must look at the pattern for $n=4,3,2$, everytime you take one product away. For $n=1$ you have a product of no terms: the empy product.

Answer (score 0):

Take $n=3$ for example.  We have to pull two defective mice, then a non-defective one.  The chance of that is $\frac {95}{100} \frac {94}{99}\frac  5{98}$  You can see the decreasing numerators end at $95-3+2=94$ and the denominators at $100-3+1=98$

For the general case, we need to have $n-1$ numbers counting down starting at  $95$.  That is $n-2$ increments, so the last one is $95-n+2$

Comment: So basically, I wasn't counting the non-defective mouse?

Comment: Your expression is correct except the $(100-n+1)!$ in the numerator should be $(100-n)!$.  You eliminated the term $100-n+1$ from the denominator which needs to be there under the $5$.

Comment: I'm a little confused, what would happen if $n=1$?